# No Animation with AnimatedSwitcher or AnimatedOpacity

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm learning flutter and I'm having behavior with the animation system.

I created a Radio Button which is a circle that should get filled when it gets clicked.

I created a stateful widget class and a state class.

In the state class, I build a :

```
   GestureDetector -> Container -> AnimatedSwitcher -> _animatedWidget
```

_animatedWidget is a Widget that changes when I click (in the GestureDetector onTap I do _changeSelect)

```
  void _changeSelect(){
    _isSelected = !_isSelected;
      if(_isSelected){
        setState(() {
          _animatedWidget = Container(width: double.infinity,height: double.infinity,decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black));
        });
      }
      else{
        setState(() {
          _animatedWidget = Container();          
        });
      }


  }
```

And this code is not working properly, it should fade in the full container and fade out the empty container but instead, it just pops in and pops out (like a classic change would do)

Here is the full code of my state class :

```
class _RadioButtonState extends State<RadioButton> {

  Widget _animatedWidget = Container();


  bool _isSelected = false;

  bool isSelected(){
    return _isSelected;
  }

  void _changeSelect(){
    _isSelected = !_isSelected;
      if(_isSelected){
        setState(() {
          _animatedWidget = Container(width: double.infinity,height: double.infinity,decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black));
        });
      }
      else{
        setState(() {
          _animatedWidget = Container();          
        });
      }


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _changeSelect,
      child:
        Container(
          width: 16.0,
          height: 16.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black)
          ),
          child: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            child: _animatedWidget,
          )

        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: I also tried with AnimatedOpacity instead of AnimatedSwitcher (with the full Container with a starting opacity of 0 increased to 1 when clicked) but it doesn't even change the view, however, the javascript looks to be working during the duration time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

---

```
Widget _animatedWidget = Container();

bool _isSelected = false;

bool isSelected() {
  return _isSelected;
}

void _changeSelect() {
  _isSelected = !_isSelected;
  if (_isSelected) {
    setState(() {
      _animatedWidget = Container(
        key: ValueKey(1),
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
      );
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _animatedWidget = Container(
        key: ValueKey(2),
      );
    });
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: _changeSelect,
        child: Container(
            width: 66.0,
            height: 66.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.black)),
            child: AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              child: _animatedWidget,
            )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh, so all I was doing wrong was not putting a key in the container ?
Can you explain briefly why the key is important ? thanks

Comment: Yes, that was the main issue with your code, actually `AnimatedSwitcher` can only distinguish between its child if they have different `Keys`, two widgets with different properties aren't considered different unless they have different keys, similarly, two widgets with exact same properties can be considered different if they have different key. Hope that explained :)